# How to call an Activity that is packaged within an external .jar library?

Tags: android, frameworks, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build a .jar library that developers can use in their own apps. I have 3 views (activities) in my library that I'd like developers to be able to present in their apps like this:

```
// Developer's activity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // This method returns an intent which calls 
            // an activity packaged in my .jar file
            startActivity(EvelynsLibrary.showView(this));

        }
    }
```

The main library class EvelynsLibrary has a static 'showView' method which accepts an activity (to get context), creates an intent based on the context and an Activity bundled in my .jar, and returns an Intent, that the developer can show using startActivity.

Not sure if this is needed, but I have also added the external activity to the calling app's AndroidManifest.xml file like so:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity"
        android:label="Evelyn"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
```

Here is my entire error (Logcat) output:

```
11-19 02:52:30.760      597-642/? E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {276 softap fwreload wlan0 STA} took too long (895ms)
11-19 02:52:35.245      597-644/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ Unexpected mtu value: android.net.wifi.WifiStateTracker@42bf90a8
11-19 12:05:26.209      597-642/? E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {457 softap fwreload wlan0 STA} took too long (917ms)
11-19 12:05:30.793      597-644/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ Unexpected mtu value: android.net.wifi.WifiStateTracker@42bf90a8
11-19 12:05:34.167    1083-1354/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
11-19 12:05:38.191    1083-1354/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
11-19 12:08:56.234    2162-2162/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-19 12:08:56.274    2162-2162/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-19 23:18:00.632   1083-11946/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
11-19 23:18:03.515   1083-11946/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
11-19 23:36:43.087      597-644/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ Unexpected mtu value: android.net.wifi.WifiStateTracker@42bf90a8
11-20 01:03:10.368  13822-13822/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:03:10.488  13822-13822/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:03:17.034  13822-13822/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:04:16.552  13822-13822/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:05:18.422  13822-13822/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

11-20 01:13:00.193  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:13:25.428  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity com.choiceofgames.diabolical.Diabolical has leaked ServiceConnection com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor$1@42b11268 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.choiceofgames.diabolical.Diabolical has leaked ServiceConnection com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor$1@42b11268 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:979)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1561)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1544)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
            at com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor.bindPlayServices(BillingProcessor.java:102)
            at com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor.<init>(BillingProcessor.java:95)
            at com.choiceofgames.choicescript.Billing.<init>(Billing.java:57)
            at com.choiceofgames.choicescript.ChoiceScriptActivity.onCreate(ChoiceScriptActivity.java:191)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 01:13:27.760  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:13:57.899  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:14:27.999  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for 

11-20 01:36:32.631  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:37:02.740  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:37:32.830  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:38:02.949  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
11-20 01:38:33.058  14643-14643/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for 
11-20 11:13:03.752      597-642/? E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {639 softap fwreload wlan0 STA} took too long (995ms)
11-20 11:13:08.276      597-644/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ Unexpected mtu value: android.net.wifi.WifiStateTracker@42bf90a8
11-20 11:13:11.629   1083-18466/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
11-20 11:13:15.303   1083-18466/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.wearable.settings
11-20 12:19:22.863      597-612/? E/WindowManager﹕ Starting window AppWindowToken{43a69c40 token=Token{42d66640 ActivityRecord{42840e90 u0 com.example.myExampleApp/.MyActivity t26}}} timed out
11-20 12:19:42.102  25049-25049/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myExampleApp, PID: 25049
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myExampleApp/com.example.myExampleApp.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
            at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
            at com.evelyn.EvelynsLibrary.showView(EvelynsLibrary.java:22)
            at com.example.myExampleApp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 12:42:19.597      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
11-20 12:42:19.597      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
11-20 12:42:20.377      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
11-20 12:42:20.377      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
11-20 12:42:20.698  26094-26100/com.example.myExampleApp E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-20 12:42:30.687      597-612/? E/WindowManager﹕ Starting window AppWindowToken{43f4bd98 token=Token{4311d8e8 ActivityRecord{42cefb90 u0 com.example.myExampleApp/.MyActivity t27}}} timed out
11-20 12:48:28.456    1083-1569/? E/PlayLoggerImpl﹕ Service was disconnected.  Will try caching.
11-20 12:49:00.297  26565-26581/? E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:254 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-20 12:49:00.358  26565-26584/? E/OMXMaster﹕ A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
11-20 12:51:29.873      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
11-20 12:51:29.873      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
11-20 12:51:30.624      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
11-20 12:51:30.624      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
11-20 12:51:32.996  26719-26719/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 26719
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyExampleStartActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapp/com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapp/com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
            at com.example.myapp.MyExampleStartActivity.onCreate(MyExampleStartActivity.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 12:51:33.977  10994-10994/? E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2121)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
11-20 12:51:38.232      833-841/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@4283e910)
11-20 12:51:38.232      833-841/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@4289b088)
11-20 12:51:38.232      833-841/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@42816e80)
11-20 12:51:38.232      833-841/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@42a4b5b8)

11-20 12:53:44.995      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
11-20 12:53:44.995      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
11-20 12:53:45.786      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
11-20 12:53:45.786      833-833/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
11-20 12:53:47.988      597-610/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_time_resp: Resetting rollover count from 0 to 1
11-20 12:53:48.138  27195-27195/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 27195
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity.setLayout(MainActivity.java:34)
            at com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:146)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 12:54:02.352      597-633/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '42877b50 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyExampleStartActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-20 12:54:05.135      597-610/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_time_resp: Resetting rollover count from 0 to 1
11-20 12:54:05.275  27304-27304/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 27304
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030002
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity.setLayout(MainActivity.java:34)
            at com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:146)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Question:** Where am I going wrong? How can I achieve this and allow a developer to call my .jars activity?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare posted. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` inside the `Intent` creation from `showView()` (`EvelynsLibrary.java` line 22). It also is not finding your manifest entry for some reason (`Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapp/com.evelyn.EvelynsActivity}`). And, as Alexander notes, use an AAR/Android library project. You can write a JAR, but JARs don't have Android resources, so any resource-related code will fail.

Comment: @CommonsWare awesome. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an Android Library project not a jar

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how about some reasons? Your answer as it stands, is too short to be very helpful, and could be a comment. Give more detail if you expect me to choose your answer.

Comment: The reason is you can not store android resources such as activity layouts in a plain jar